# How do we prevent Google Sheets from slowing down

Tags: google-sheets

We are using Google sheets for simultaneous entry of several users. We observe that after a number of users start to entry at the same time, Google sheets starts to slow down.

We have a stable internet connection. What can we do to keep Google Sheets from slowing down? Do we limit the number of users use the Google sheet at the same time? Is there any optimization we can do?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely witnessing a *correlation* not a *causation* between the number of users entering information on the sheet and the speed of the sheet.

Is there conditional formatting on the sheet?  Are there a lot of formulas? What kinds of functions are in the formulas?

The thing that is likely slowing the sheet down is the number of calculations being made that are *dependent* on the cells in which your users are entering information.  This makes it difficult to both diagnose and advise on the next best course of action.